# How i set position text on Listview with React-Native in Android and iOS

Tags: ios, listview, react-native, position

I am a newbie developer. I'm currently developing apps using **React-Native** on two platforms, **Android** and **iOS**.

I have several constraints when designing this app on the two platforms I use. This app is similar to chat. For the wrapping compiler I use `Listview`. But there are constraints when running on the **iOS** platform.

**My code is as follows:**

```js
<View style={Styles.container}>
        <View style={Styles.conversation}>
          {this.messages.length > 0
            ? <ListView
              enableEmptySections
              style={Styles.messageList}
              ref={ref => (this.listView = ref)}
              onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
                  this.listView.scrollTo({
                    y: contentHeight,
                  });
                }
              }}
              dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(this.messages)}
              renderRow={item => <Message data={item} key={item.key} />}
            />
            : <Text style={Styles.welcome_message}>Welcome to Kelle</Text>}
        </View>
```

The code above on **Android** goes well. But when it runs on **iOS**, the chat text position in the `Listview` becomes random. Like the picture below:

[image]

Has anyone ever experienced anything like this? How should I solve this problem?

Comment: what do you mean random? can you upload SS for android as well to compare?

Comment: i mean if i input text like `task` the position of the text in up is not in accordance with size layout. This is for SS the app in Android :

[SS Android][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vVHe.png